# simple program to determine type of triangle giving weird results

Tags: c

the program checks simple triangle types : equilateral , isosceles , right-angled etc . but im getting really weird results.

my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int comparator (const void * elem1, const void * elem2) {
    int f = *((float*)elem1);
    int s = *((float*)elem2);
    if (f > s) return 1;
    if (f < s) return -1;
    return 0;
}
void checkTriangles(float *num){
    float a = *num;
    float b = *(num + 1);
    float c = *(num + 2);

    if((a*a + b*b)==c*c){
        printf("right angled triangle");
    }
    else if(a==b || b==c || c==a){
        printf("isosceles triangle");
    }
    else if(a==b && b==c){
        printf("equilateral triangle");
    }
    else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a && ((a+b)>c)){
        printf("normal triangle");
    }
    else{
        printf("invalid");
    }
}

int main(void){
    char c = 'a';
    char str[12];
    float num[3];
    while(c!='q'){
        printf("\n\nenter the sides : ");
        fgets(str , sizeof(str) , stdin);
        sscanf(str , "%f%f%f", num , num + 1 , num + 2);

        qsort(num, sizeof(num)/sizeof(*num), sizeof(*num), comparator);
        printf("\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", num , num + 1 , num + 2);

        checkTriangles(num);

        printf("\nenter q to quit.. any other to continue : ");
        c=getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

however , im getting real odd outputs like this :

[image]

i know that using quick sort for something like this is overkill , but i wanted to keep it short and use comparators also, just for fun.

**edit** : iv added the full code , and checked the comparator to check for floats , but still getting the same output.

Comment: Give us the `main` code where you actually call these functions.

Comment: How do you call the `checkTriangles` function? What's the argument? How is the argument declared? And what is its values? You might want to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, warning messages from the compiler are *important*, as they usually indicate you do something wrong so please edit your question to include them as well (as text and not as a screenshot).

Comment: provided. i wanted to provide the whole thing , but i was getting a warning notification. i hope it helps now.

Comment: your comparator compares integers and not floats.

Comment: Your num[] array is of type float, so you need to write your comparator function to compare floats, not ints.

Comment: Change the order of the checks for equilateral and isosceles. An equilateral triangle is an isosceles triangle as well.

Comment: @AlexFarber sorry for that ! i missed checking that part. original code was for ints.

Comment: One minor issue: You have used condition for Isoceles triangle before Equilateral triangle. Since an Equilateral triangle is Isoceles, therefore you get such output.

Comment: Treating arrays and pointer differently is often better in understanding the program. Use `&num[2]` if `num` is an array, if it is a pointer use `num + 2`.

Comment: Also, a right angle triangle can also be an isosceles triangle, or a normal triangle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a big problem which is undefined behavior:

```
printf("\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", num , num + 1 , num + 2);
```

Here you use the *pointers* to the values in the `printf` call, but you should use the *values*.

Change to e.g.

```
printf("\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", num[0], num[1], num[2]);
```

Note: There's no need to keep using pointer dereference, you have an array so why not use array syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The if condition:

```
else if(a==b || b==c || c==a){
    printf("isosceles triangle");
}
```

Will evaluate to true for isosceles triangles AND equilateral triangles - when you pass `a = 5, b = 5, c = 5,` this if-condition evaluates to true and isosceles is printed. You want something like:

```
else if( (a==b || b==c || c==a) && !(a==b && a==c){
    printf("isosceles triangle");
}
```

And then when you give an equilateral triangle, you will get the correct thing printed.

Alternatively you could just put the equilateral case before the isosceles case, but that'd be bad practice. Explicit is always better than implicit.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. But my primary problem is that its giving me really odd outputs